# How map a dictionary attribute in Restkit 0.2

Tags: ios, dictionary, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm creating an app which posts a "Photo" object that has a metadata dictionary which includes the photo's EXIF data as a dictionary in Photo object, but the metadata dictionary doesn't seem to be getting included in the JSON post.  I'm guessing this is because you're not supposed to map arbitrary dictionaries, and instead are supposed to turn them into objects.  The problem is I don't know what keys are going to be in this dictionary, so I can't transform keys into some other field like in the example.  Any help or advice on a better way to do this would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Here's the class I'm trying to map:

```
@interface Photo : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) UInt64 user;
@property (nonatomic) UInt64 id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *time_taken;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *metadata;

@end
```

And the request code

```
Photo *peanutPhoto = [[DFPeanutPhoto alloc] initWithDFPhoto:photo];
    NSData *thumbnailData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo.thumbnail, IMAGE_UPLOAD_JPEG_QUALITY);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self.objectManager
                                    multipartFormRequestWithObject:peanutPhoto
                                    method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                    path:@"photos/"
                                    parameters:nil
                                    constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
                                        [formData appendPartWithFileData:thumbnailData name:@"file"
                                                                fileName:@"thumbnail.jpg"
                                                                mimeType:@"image/jpg"];
                                    }];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *requestOperation = [self.objectManager objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:nil failure:nil];


    [self.objectManager enqueueObjectRequestOperation:requestOperation];
```

Here are the trace logs

```
2014-05-01 15:47:50.136 69891:3507] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:952 Starting mapping operation...
2014-05-01 15:47:50.137 69891:3907] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:952 Starting mapping operation...
2014-05-01 15:47:50.138 69891:3907] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:953 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x10ca585e0> for '__NSDictionaryM' object. Mapping values from object Photo: user:59 id:0 time_taken:2014-04-14T16:42:13Z metadata:{
    ColorModel = RGB;
    Depth = 8;
    PixelHeight = 1136;
    PixelWidth = 640;
    "{DFCameraRollExtras}" =     {
        DateTimeCreated = "2014:04:14 16:42:13";
    };
    "{PNG}" =     {
        InterlaceType = 0;
    };
} ((null)) to object {
} with object mapping (null)
2014-05-01 15:47:50.137 69891:3507] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:953 Performing mapping operation: <RKMappingOperation 0x10ef62310> for '__NSDictionaryM' object. Mapping values from object Photo: user:59 id:0 time_taken:2014-04-15T15:11:31Z metadata:{
    ColorModel = RGB;
    DPIHeight = 240;
    DPIWidth = 240;
    Depth = 8;
    PixelHeight = 1208;
    PixelWidth = 3264;
    "{DFCameraRollExtras}" =     {
        DateTimeCreated = "2014:04:15 15:11:31";
    };
    "{ExifAux}" =     {
        LensInfo =         (
            "4.12",
            "4.12",
            "2.2",
            "2.2"
        );
        LensModel = "iPhone 5s back camera 4.12mm f/2.2";
    };
    "{Exif}" =     {
        ApertureValue = "2.275007044237813";
        BrightnessValue = "9.726902173913043";
        ColorSpace = 0;
        ComponentsConfiguration =         (
            1,
            2,
            3,
            0
        );
        DateTimeDigitized = "2014:04:15 15:11:31";
        DateTimeOriginal = "2014:04:15 15:11:31";
        ExifVersion =         (
            2,
            3
        );
        ExposureMode = 0;
        ExposureProgram = 0;
        ExposureTime = "0.0007142857142857143";
        FNumber = "2.2";
        Flash = 0;
        FlashPixVersion =         (
            1,
            0
        );
        FocalLenIn35mmFilm = 0;
        FocalLength = "4.12";
        ISOSpeedRatings =         (
            0
        );
        LensMake = Apple;
        LensModel = "iPhone 5s back camera 4.12mm f/2.2";
        LensSpecification =         (
            "4.12",
            "4.12",
            "2.2",
            "2.2"
        );
        MeteringMode = 0;
        PixelXDimension = 0;
        PixelYDimension = 0;
        SceneCaptureType = 0;
        SceneType = 1;
        SensingMethod = 0;
        ShutterSpeedValue = "10.4512105649303";
        SubjectArea =         (
            1631,
            1223,
            1795,
            1077
        );
        SubsecTimeDigitized = 755;
        SubsecTimeOriginal = 755;
        WhiteBalance = 0;
    };
    "{TIFF}" =     {
        DateTime = "2014:04:16 11:37:00";
        Make = Apple;
        Model = "iPhone 5s";
        ResolutionUnit = 0;
        Software = "Adobe Photoshop Lightroom 5.4 (Macintosh)";
        XResolution = 240;
        YResolution = 240;
    };
} ((null)) to object {
} with object mapping (null)
2014-05-01 15:47:50.138 69891:3907] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'user' to 'user'
2014-05-01 15:47:50.139 69891:3507] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'user' to 'user'
2014-05-01 15:47:50.139 69891:3907] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'user' to 'user'. Value: 59
2014-05-01 15:47:50.139 69891:5e03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:130 Cached property inspection for Class 'NSMutableDictionary': {
    fileHFSFlags =     {
        isPrimitive = 1;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = fileHFSFlags;
    };
    fileHFSResourceForkSize =     {
        isPrimitive = 1;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = fileHFSResourceForkSize;
    };
}
2014-05-01 15:47:50.140 69891:3507] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'user' to 'user'. Value: 59
2014-05-01 15:47:50.140 69891:3907] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'id' to 'id'
2014-05-01 15:47:50.140 69891:5e03] D restkit.object_mapping:RKPropertyInspector.m:130 Cached property inspection for Class 'Photo': {
    id =     {
        isPrimitive = 1;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = id;
    };
    metadata =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSDictionary;
        name = metadata;
    };
    "time_taken" =     {
        isPrimitive = 0;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSString;
        name = "time_taken";
    };
    user =     {
        isPrimitive = 1;
        keyValueCodingClass = NSNumber;
        name = user;
    };
}
2014-05-01 15:47:50.140 69891:3907] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'id' to 'id'. Value: 0
2014-05-01 15:47:50.140 69891:3507] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'id' to 'id'
2014-05-01 15:47:50.141 69891:3507] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'id' to 'id'. Value: 0
2014-05-01 15:47:50.141 69891:3907] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'time_taken' to 'time_taken'
2014-05-01 15:47:50.142 69891:3907] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'time_taken' to 'time_taken'. Value: 2014-04-14T16:42:13Z
2014-05-01 15:47:50.142 69891:3507] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:550 Mapping attribute value keyPath 'time_taken' to 'time_taken'
2014-05-01 15:47:50.142 69891:3907] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1021 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2014-05-01 15:47:50.142 69891:3507] T restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:572 Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'time_taken' to 'time_taken'. Value: 2014-04-15T15:11:31Z
2014-05-01 15:47:50.143 69891:3507] D restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:1021 Finished mapping operation successfully...
2014-05-01 15:47:50:265 69891:5e03]
```

Comment: You should show your mapping and the result JSON you get

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use a relationship and a nested mapping for the dictionary. Use an `RKDynamicMapping` for that so that it can inspect the keys of the metadata and create a bespoke mapping, simply using the array of keys.